# Changing data format from DataTime to general r

Tags: r, excel

I am trying to extract data from one of the Excel files I have. However, R puts some data in DateTime format instead of numeric format even though data is numeric in Excel( data is in custom format and seems to be numeric when general format is applied). I tried to change it via 'as.numeric()' function but it didn't work. The code used for the task above is as follows:

```
library(readxl)
l<-as.data.frame(read_excel(choose.files(),sheet=2,range="C6:BG123"))
vec1<-c("t",rep("n",ncol(l)-1))
#Changing columns to the appropriate format
for(j in 1:length(vec1)){
      if(vec1[j]=="t"){
        l[,j]<-as.character(l[,j])
      }else if(vec1[j]=="n"){
        l[,j]<-as.numeric(l[,j])
      }
```

The final output after this code is data with huge numerical values instead of actual numbers presented in Excel.

The excel data can be found here: https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2019/01/20190110-NHS-111-MDS-time-series-to-December2018-1.xlsx

I would like to know where I am wrong and if it is something to do with an initial format of data in excel, how can I change the format in Excel to 'General' from R before importing data.

Comment: You should give an example of your input/output data

Comment: @Alexandregeorges Data source provided as requested

Comment: force `read_excel` to read the correct formats by setting the `col_types`-argument correctly.... besides, read_excel already produces a tibble, so you probably don't need the `as.data.frame()` around it

Comment: I don't have data in the sheet 2.
Some solutions :
- Use the button "Import dataset" from RStudio (you can modify the format in the UI)
- Use the `col_types` argument as menitonned by Wimpel
- Keep only the rows and columns you need in the input data

Comment: @Wimpel that solves it. If you post your suggestion as an answer, I'll accept it. Regardless, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force `read_excel()` to read the correct formats by setting the `col_types`-argument of the function.